# How to select a word on double click using the Range-Interface?

Tags: javascript, range, selection

For example:

```html
<span>"This is s"<span style="color:1abc9c">ent</span>"e<strong>nc</strong>"e to be select"</span>
```

The sentence is like this: *"This is sentence to be select"*. Now when I double click anywhere inside the word *sentence* it should select that word. How to select this word?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **double click on any word** in the sentence to select the word *"sentence"* **but prevent selecting the entire sentence**:

```js
let sentence = document.getElementsByClassName('sentence');
let word = document.getElementById('word');

Array.from(sentence).forEach(sentence =>
  sentence.addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(word);
    sel.addRange(range);
  })
);
```

```css
.sentence {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<span class="sentence">This is the </span><span id="word">sentence</span><span class="sentence"> to be selected.</span>
```

Or if you want to **double click on any word** in the sentence to select the word *"sentence"*:

```js
let sentence = document.getElementById('sentence');
let word = document.getElementById('word');

sentence.addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(word);
  sel.addRange(range);
});
```

```html
<span id="sentence">This is the <span id="word">sentence</span> to be selected.</span>
```

Or if you want to **single click on any word** in the sentence to select the word *"sentence"*:

```js
let sentence = document.getElementById('sentence');
let word = document.getElementById('word');

sentence.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(word);
  sel.addRange(range);
});
```

```html
<span id="sentence">This is the <span id="word">sentence</span> to be selected.</span>
```

Or if you want to **single click** on *"sentence"* to select it:

```js
let word = document.getElementById('word');

word.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(word);
  sel.addRange(range);
});
```

```html
This is the <span id="word">sentence</span> to be selected.
```

Or if you want to **single click** on *"sentence"* to select it using **CSS** with [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select):

```css
span {
  user-select: all;
}
```

```html
This is the <span>sentence</span> to be selected.
```

Comment: @AvinashJadhav Did my answer suit your needs or should I elaborate? If it did, please consider accepting it. If not, let me know.